# use jpegtran and optipng in website linux php

Tags: php, linux, jpegtran

I couldn't find any guide to tell me how to produce optimized images in php environment. I have a website under linux, with php, and cannot install* anything.

Somebody suggest the use of *exec*, lot of people in github seems to have developed some wrapper... but I cannot undertand how to place this softwares in my web space. For example jpegtran (which I use in windows as a stand-alone executable) probably doesn't work on my server.

Can somebody tell me how to proceed - if it is even possible?

---

EDIT

(*) I have no rights to install anything in that server. I can "install" php packages (e.g. wordpress ecc.), I have access to ftp. I found out that even executables cannot be run. This seems to be a losing battle.

Comment: first thing to do would be to check if you can run these things `shell_exec('optipng -o7 /path/to/your.png');` and `shell_exec('jpegtran ...`

Comment: @cmorrissey are ou suggesting that the server might alreadyy have them installed?

Comment: It might! you won't know unless you check.

Comment: noop... no jpegtran or optipng pre-installed...

Comment: *and cannot install anything* do you mean you don't know how to install on this server, or you literally cannot install anything? Can you install PHP packages? What *can* you do? It's not clear what kind of solution you are looking for...

Comment: @GrishaLevit added edit